# Alpine Linux library missing GLIBCXX in libstdc++.so

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, alpine-linux

I am trying to use Alpine Linux for a containerized C++ application. We are trying to switch from Ubuntu to Alpine Linux due to image size.

I encountered several errors in the C++ build process, and most of them were resolved by installing the appropriate package. I have finally reached a point where I cannot get past this particular error:

```
undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4'
```

Upon some research, I came upon a suggestion to check the `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28` file for presence of `GLIBCXX_3.4` using the following command, with the output:

```
bash-5.0# strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

There's not `GLIBCXX_3.4` or any version of `GLIBCXX` or `GLIBC`.

Running the same command in Ubuntu yields the following:

```
 root@379aa5a61642:/app# strings /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so | grep GLIB
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Clearly, Ubuntu seems to have all the GLIB versions. Can anyone help me with how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need glibc binaries at all. Alpine's built-in C++ support is built against MUSL, and doesn't need glibc. My experience is that, the more glibc support I have to add to an Alpine image, the more I wish I'd just used UBI or something instead. Alpine works best as a base image if you _don't_ need glibc.

Comment: We are using a proprietary library and I think that library references GLIBC. Our plan was to utilize dockerized alpine linux to build our application, but it has not been working out so far.

Comment: There are certainly a few glibc extensions to C that are widely used, and don't exist in MUSL; but for a library to 'reference glibc' sounds like a somewhat dodgy practice to me. Other than to use functions that only exist in glibc, I'm not even sure how a library author could accomplish that.

Comment: It happens quite automatically when you compile software against given C library. For instance a simple application compiled against Glibc 2.12 will probably not run on Glibc 2.5 due to symbol versioning. It would be better to compile software against target platform (MUSL in case of Alpine), but it you're stuck to a precompiled library you would probably need to use a Glibc-based system.